# Ionic 4 ion-tabs - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-tabs

My **app-routing.module.ts**:

```
  {
    path: 'conversation-tabs',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'conv-conversation',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren:
              '/conv-conversation.module#ConvConversationPageModule',
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'conversation-files',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren:
              '/conversation-files.module#ConversationFilesPageModule',
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/conversation-tabs/conv-conversation',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
```

HTML in **conv-conversation.html**:

```
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" color="light">
          <ion-tab-button tab="conv-conversation">
              <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>Messages</ion-label>
              <ion-badge>{{ unreadMsgs }}</ion-badge>
          </ion-tab-button>

          <ion-tab-button tab="conversation-files">
              <ion-icon name="folder"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>Files</ion-label>
          </ion-tab-button>
      </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>
```

This is how my process works:

```
Login -> Home -> Pick Conversation (contains button to go to conversation-tabs)
```

`conversation-tabs` redirects to `conv-conversation` which is going to act as the 'home' for my tabs. At the bottom of `conv-conversation.html` is the HTML code above. When I click the `conversation-files` button, I get this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'conversation-tabs/conv-conversation/conversation-files'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'conversation-tabs/conv-conversation/conversation-files'

I'm not really sure what the issue is since my routing is set. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link that leads to `conversation-files` is not set correctly, because it apparently appends the path instead of replacing it.
I believe you haven't correctly set up you component structure. You need to have a `ConversationTabsPage` (name it as you like) component at your `path: 'conversation-tabs'` and then put your tab buttons there:

```
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" color="light">
          <ion-tab-button tab="conv-conversation">
              <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>Messages</ion-label>
              <ion-badge>{{ unreadMsgs }}</ion-badge>
          </ion-tab-button>

          <ion-tab-button tab="conversation-files">
              <ion-icon name="folder"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>Files</ion-label>
          </ion-tab-button>
      </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-toolbar>
```

so in your **app-routing.module.ts** you would have next:

```
{
    path: 'conversation-tabs',
    component: ConversationTabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'conv-conversation',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren:
              '/conv-conversation.module#ConvConversationPageModule',
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'conversation-files',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren:
              '/conversation-files.module#ConversationFilesPageModule',
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/conversation-tabs/conv-conversation',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Also remove tab buttons from your **conv-conversation.html**.
I referred to this [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-tabs?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftabs%2Ftabs.page.html).

**EDIT**: I've created another [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-tabs-zmat9u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fconversation-tabs%2Fconversation-tabs.page.html) for your specific use case where it works. The reason why it was showing blank content when routing was working was because your `ion-tabs` were wrapped in `ion-toolbar`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Nope. No errors this time. It just doesn't change page/tabs

Comment: So there is difference... I changed my answer a bit, can you please try it?

Comment: Yes. My bad. I was looking at something else. I've just tried out your new answer. It does redirect to the "files" tab but this error still appears:
`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'conversation-tabs/conv-conversation/conversation-files'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'conversation-tabs/conv-conversation/conversation-files'`

Comment: When it's on the "files" tab, the "messages" tab does not work and I get this error: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'conversation-tabs/conversation-files/conv-conversation'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'conversation-tabs/conversation-files/conv-conversation`

Comment: From the error I can see that it still constructs wrong url... I suggest switching back to old solution and subscribing to routerEvents somewhere and log what happens there. Jus to see if changing clicking tab triggers navigation. Like this `router.events.subscribe((event) => console.log(event))`. Then you can see if it triggered navigation and if yes, where it got cancelled.

Comment: ok, I see what you did wrong, I am gonna updated my answer, please try it then

Comment: Are you saying to move the tab buttons to `conversation-tabs.html`? I do have a `ConversationTabsPage` which is `conversation-tabs`

Comment: Yes, but you also have to reference it in router like how I defined it in the answer.

Comment: Adding the component to `app-routing.module.ts` causes this error: `ERROR in Could not resolve module /conv-conversation.module relative to src\app\app-routing.module.ts`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207525/discussion-between-blind-despair-and-j-do).